# replace system() with non-blocking function

Tags: c

I don't want to use system() in my C program, because system(3) blocks and this is not what I want. What is the optimal way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-blocking version of system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002513/non-blocking-version-of-system)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that a quick and dirty action is to call sytem(command &). the & will spawn the new process.

Comment: Absolutely +1. `system()` is platform-dependent anyway. Instead of making a mess of your source with `fork()` or stuff like that, use the shell that `system()` gives you access to.

Comment: great solution much better than fork if you aks me

Answer (score 8):

Use `fork()` to create a new process and then use `system()` (or any `exec` function) in it. The original process will then be able to continue executing.

Answer (score 8):

The answer depends on what your real goal is. You don't say what platform you're on, and I know very little about Windows, so this only covers your options on linux/unix.

1. You just want to spawn another program, and don't need to interact with it. In this case, call [`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork), and then in the child process run [`execve()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execve) (or related function).
2. You want to interact with another program. In this case, use [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen).
3. You want part of your program to run as a subprocess. In this case, use `fork()`, and call whatever functions you need to run in the child.
4. You need to interact with part of your program running as a subprocess. Call [`pipe()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pipe) so you have a file descriptor to communicate through, then call `fork()` and use the file descriptor pair to communicate. Alternatively, you could communicate through a socket, message queue, shared memory, etc.

Comment: Nice rundown of the options at hand, and how to choose between them.

Comment: `fork()` then `system()` will leave a useless process hanging around for the shell to finish. It is better to call `execve()` or similar in the child process instead of `system()`. If you want to use the shell's features, then exec `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to use `popen`. It creates new processes and allows you to redirect the process output to your own process.

Answer (score 3):

If in windows, use the `ShellExecute()` function from the Windows API.

If in Unix, go for `fork()` then `system()` as mentioned.