# system function flaws

Tags: c

We are using C in Linux. Is there any possibility that `system()` function can behave in an unexpected manner, especially when we handle signals?

We found that sometimes, the `system()` function blocks the execution or it throws `SIGSEGV`.

e.g:

```
system ( "/bin/mv a b" );
```

Are there any known flaws in using `system()` that would explain this?

Comment: `system()` *always* blocks until the command is done.

Comment: but mv command doesnt take much time , right ?

Comment: it depends: if you are moving big files from different partitions it may takes some time to finish

Comment: I know system works fine at most of the times , all i want to know is when and all it may fail or its behaviour is unexpected !

Comment: @Overbose , no I move the file in a same file system ! , although my problem is it blocks undefinitely some times or some times I got sigsegv , so blocking only is not a problem !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `system()` function does what it is supposed to do perfectly well.  The behaviour is pretty reliable as long as it is invoked correctly.  It has two modes of operation:

1. Check whether there is a command interpreter available - when the argument is a null pointer.
2. Run the command given, waiting for the command to complete before returning.

So, the `system()` statement blocks until the shell that runs the command completes.  On Unix-like systems, the command invoked is effectively:

```
"sh", "-c", "...argument to system...", NULL
```

This means that the string passed is interpreted by the shell.  How long that takes depends on the command that is executed.  You can consider using the shell notations to run the command in background if you need to:

```
system("( /bin/mv a b & )");
```

There are few circumstances where `system()` will itself generate SIGSEGV.  You would have to pass it an invalid pointer, a pointer to somewhere invalid in the program.

Answer (score 0):

The `system()` call is [supposed to block](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html) until execution is finished. If it takes an hour to move a to b, the process or thread calling `system()` *will* block for an hour. Knowing this, strange behavior can be explained.

If you expect `system()` to return immediately, it probably means that you expect code that runs after calling it to have been entered by the time you see the strange behavior. It is very likely that, due to `system()` taking longer than expected, some area of memory wasn't allocated or initialized. This is likely the cause of the segmentation fault when another thread or process tried to access it.

In other words, if you didn't *expect* `system()` to block, you probably assumed that code coming after it would run much sooner than it actually did.

Debunking that would be a topic for another question. The answer to this one is no, you aren't seeing flaws in the `system()` function, it is behaving exactly as expected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838565/replace-system-with-non-blocking-function

Comment: @Michael - I think the SEGV the OP is seeing is (likely) due to code coming after system() not being reached in the expected amount of time, since the OP didn't expect it to block. I updated my answer. Since the OP is passing a string literal as an argument, it seemed a likely explanation.