# time taken by forked child process

Tags: c++, system, fork

This is a sequel to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10066591/984260). I am using fork to create child process. Inside child, I am giving command to run a process as follows:

```
if((childpid=fork())==0)
{
system("./runBinary ");
exit(1)
}
```

My runBinary has the functionality of measuring how much time it takes from start to finish.

What amazes me is that when I run runBinary directly on command-line, it takes ~60 seconds. However, when I run it as a child process, it takes more, like ~75 or more. Is there something which I can do or am currently doing wrong, which is leading to this?

Thanks for the help in advance.
MORE DETAILS: I am running on linux RHEL server, with 24 cores. I am measuring CPU time. At a time, I only fork 8 child (sequentially), each of which is bound to different core, using taskset (not shown in code). The system is not loaded except for my own program.

Comment: Maybe it takes 15 seconds for your sleeping parent process to get woken by the o/s after the child exits?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you tell how to confirm that? Thanks

Comment: @sarnold actually it is runBinary which is itself measuring the time.

Comment: If runBinary is doing the timing, then it is not clear that the time taken to wake the sleeping parent is the issue.  Given the update about a 24 core machine and using `taskset()`, then try running it without using `taskset()` or CPU binding.  Is the `runBinary` program itself multi-threaded?  Could it be running into more contention when you run 8 from your own binary than when you run them one at a time from the command line?  (You do run 8 from the command line, don't you?)

Comment: Does performance depend upon the [`/proc/sys/kernel/sched_autogroup_enabled`](http://lwn.net/Articles/415742/) variable?

Comment: @sarnold Thanks. However, on my server and even local computer, this variable/file is not there. only: /proc/sys/kernel/sched_interactive is there.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler runBinary is not multi-threaded. Each of its instance is independent of each other. Its memory usage is 2% (seeing from top). I don't think it causes contention. I will try to run it w/o taskset soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system() function is to invoke the shell. You can do anything inside it, including running a script. This gives you a lot of flexibility, but it comes with a price: you're loading a shell, and then runBinary inside it. Although I don't think loading the shell would be responsible to so much time difference (15 seconds is a lot, after all), since it  doesn't seem you need that - just to run the app - try using something from the [exec()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) family instead.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is very convincing. Do you think exec family is faster? The reason I did not use execvp was that in system I could do system("./Binary argument1 argument2 ");, whereas, I could not do so in execvp. Can you tell.

Comment: Well, just not having to load the shell and interpret the command line given should provide a speed increase. About the command line, I didn't understand, what exectly you said you can't do? You can pass arguments to it, the only additional work is that you have to put the arguments in an array - if using the execv variants - or at least have the binary name in a separated string - if using the execl variants. Those things can be done, for instance, with strtok.

Answer (score 0):

Without profiling the application, if the parent process which forks has a large memory space, you might find that there is time spent attempting to fork the process itself, and attempts to duplicate the memory space.

This isn't a problem in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, but was in earlier versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.