# Blocking version of execvp (windows)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, exec

This question is exactly the opposite of [Non-blocking version of system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002513/non-blocking-version-of-system)

I want to substitute the current process by another one (not create another one).

I want to start (for instance) `notepad`, but in a blocking way (I don't want to get the prompt until `notepad` is closed.

In the Windows shell I just do

```
cmd /c notepad
```

(`notepad` auto-detachs from prompt if not prefixed by `cmd /c`)

In C, using `system` I just do

```
system("notepad");
```

But this is forking behind the scenes. I want to *replace* the current process by `notepad`, and I want it to be blocking.

I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  char * const args[] = {"cmd","/c","notepad",NULL};
  execvp(args[0],args);
}
```

`notepad` runs, but the console returns to the prompt immediately.(non-blocking). I want it to block, and I don't want to use `fork` as it would create another process: I want to *replace* the current process.

(I have tried with a custom blocking executable, and it doesn't block either. So `cmd /c notepad` example is as good as any other one)

So, If I run this executable I just built from a parent process:

- I don't want the process to return to the parent process until the `notepad` process exits
- I want to be able to get output from the command (`notepad` isn't a good example in that case)
- I don't want to create an extra process (this is part of a massive multiprocessing application, we can't afford to create 2 processes, we need to keep 1 process for each run)

Is it even possible?

Comment: Why are you exec-ing "cmd" rather than just "notepad" directly?

Comment: What is "blocking"? If you "substitute" the process, what will get blocked then?

Comment: *I want to replace the current process by notepad* - what you mean under *replace* ?!

Comment: *I don't want the process to return to the parent process until the notepad process exits* - this is absolute impossible in windows. but you can wait for child process exit. in what is problem ?

Comment: call `CreateProcessW` and wait on it handle in place. however this is not very good - wait in place, always better continue execution self, instead wait, and do some task when child terminated

Comment: I want to replace the current process, the way `execvp` replaces (doesn't create a _child_ process). It works but the process then returns to the shell and keeps running; I want it to block.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you *really* trying to accomplish? Keep in mind, that you *will* be able to afford 2 processes, once you find out, that there is no API (or native API) call in Windows, that 'replaces' a process. This also sounds like premature optimization. You don't have a proof-of-concept implemented, so there is no way, that you have actually profiled, whether that is fast enough. If it isn't, it stands to reason, that your architecture is pathological, one way or another.

Comment: again - what you mean under **replace** ? *execvp replaces (doesn't create a child process)* - really ?

Comment: yes, `_execvp` (Microsoft API) does exactly that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xw6zy53.aspx. But detaches from the console that was running the "original" program. This console I want to keep "blocked". And I cannot seem to achieve this without creating a subprocess.

Comment: You are reading something into the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/execvp-wexecvp), that's not there. Specifically, *"[e]ach of these functions loads and executes a **new process**"*. I'm not sure how you interpret that to mean, that the currently running process were replaced. That's not what's happening, and that's not what the documentation says either.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre *This console I want to keep "blocked". And I cannot seem to achieve this without creating a subprocess.* That's because **something** has to block waiting for your new process.  Since nothing in the OS does that, you do have to create a child process so the original process can block and wait for the child process to exit.

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings The posted code code causes the compiler to output several warning messages. 1) unused parameter `argc`  2) unused parameter `argv[]` 3) implicit declaration of function  `execvp()` (due to missing header: `unistd.h`) 4) the second parameter to `execvp()` should be declared as `char * const args[] ///'  not `const char * args[]`

Comment: ok, fixed. But the question is still unanswered (I doubt it will be)

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly clear what you want - the current process can't wait on the child process if it's *replaced* by the child executable via an `execv*()` function.

A possible `system()` replacement - on Windows - is [`_spawnvp()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/spawnvp-wspawnvp):

```
intptr_t _spawnvp(  
   int mode,  
   const char *cmdname,  
   const char *const *argv   
);
```

Just use

```
int rc = _spawnvp( _P_WAIT, command, args );
```

(I suspect the reason this exact functionality isn't available on POSIX systems is that it's easily implemented on POSIX via `fork()`, `exec*()`, and a variation of `wait()`. Windows equivalents of those are a bit more complex.)

One thing to be careful of when using Windows `_spawn*()` functions is filenames with spaces in them.  I've had some real issues passing such filenames via this function and had to quote them.

Comment: Just a note for other viewers...this is a Windows-only thing.

Comment: The UNIX equivalent would be [`posix_spawn`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, if you're looking to reliably couple this spawned process to the current process, even if the current process is terminated, then assign it to a Job object that's configured to kill-on-close and allow silent breakaway. (Prior to Windows 8 a process can only be assigned to a single Job. If you use `CreateProcess` you can flag the create to break away from the current Job, if possible.)