# Trying to run a C++ executable inside a C++ code halts the program

Tags: c++, python-3.x, pysimplegui

My goal : To display a simple message box ("Object Detected") whenever an object is detected in the webcam.

Ive got a C++ opencv code which displays the webcam (display_cam.cc).

Ive another basic PySimpleGUI code which is being run inside another c++ code which simply displays
a text box with text "Object Detected" (gui.cc).

Inside the display_cam.cc I entered this line `system("./gui");`

Now the problem is that whenever the camera detects an object, the GUI box flashes but then its halting/pausing the code. Ive to close the GUI box and then the camera stream continues, until an object is detected again and the code pauses again with GUI flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) will always block until the command exits. It needs to, because it returns the command's exit code.

You have a few ways around this:

1. Put the `std::system()` call in its own [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).
2. Use platform-specific features in the command string to make it non-blocking. For example, on Linux, macOS, or any other platform where `std::system()` happens to get you a Posix shell, you can try:

   ```cpp
   system("./gui &")
   ```

   The trailing ampersand (`&`) [runs the process in the background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line).
3. Use other platform-specific APIs instead of `std::system()`. See [Non-blocking version of system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002513/non-blocking-version-of-system) (which is about *C* APIs, not specifically *C++*, but the solutions should be compatible).
4. Somehow rewrite your `./gui` program to exit its main process immediately while keeping its graphical window open. Again, using platform-specific process control APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is for the "./gui" process to run independently of (i.e. in parallel with) the execution of parent process, and you're on a Mac or Linux/Unix system, the easiest way to achieve that is:

```
system("./gui &");   // the ampersand means "run in the background"
```

If you need to run on Windows, OTOH, you'd probably need to call the Win32 [CreateProcess()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) function instead.

Spawning a child process simply to present a message dialog isn't a very good design, though, so if possible I suggest creating a message dialog from within your existing GUI process instead.

Comment: How to then kill this process ? Else there could be lots of such processes being spawned whenever an object is detected